# Test a method that does something as well as throws an exception

Tags: nunit, moq

I'm getting started with TDD (and MoQ). I have a method that takes in an Order and creates a unique CustomerId for that Order.

```
public class CustomerService
    {

        public CustomerService(IOrderRepository orderRepo)
        {
            _orderRepo = orderRepo;
        }

        public string Create(Order order)
        {
            //1. Save the Order that comes in, irrespective of being valid or not.
            _orderRepo.Save(order);

            //2. If the order is invalid, throw an exception.
            if (!isValid(order))
                throw new ArgumentException();

            //3. Create a Customer, generate a unique CustomerId and return that.
            return createCustomerAndGenerateCustomerId(order);
        }

    }
```

The following test doesn't seem to be working correctly:

```
    [Test]
    [ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentException))]
    public void Create_WhenPassedInvalidOrder_StillPersistsIt()
    {
        //Arrange
        var order = new Order(); //This is invalid, as it has some mandatory fields missing
        var mockOrderRepo = new Mock<IOrderRepository>();
        var customerService = new CustomerService(mockOrderRepo.Object);

        //Act
        customerService.Create(order);  //This should call Save() on the order repo, but still throw an exception.

        //Assert
        mockOrderRepo.Verify(o => o.Save(order), Times.Once());
    }
```

This test is always passing, even if I don't call _orderRepo.Save(). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have to decide what do you want to assert in your test: do you want to assert that an exception was thrown or do you want to assert that your `Save` method was called, because you cannot do both when using the `ExpectedException` attribute...

Comment: If I try to debug, program execution is not stopping at throw new ArgumentException(), but continues along in the method. Is that due to ExpectedException?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `ExpectedException` in this scenario because Nunit will try/catch the exception on the test level so your `mockOrderRepo.Verify` never gets called.

So you manually need to try catch your `customerService.Create` call - and if you want manually assert on the thrown exception - or you the [`Assert.Throws` if you're using Nunit 2.5 or higher](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=exceptionAsserts&r=2.5.1):

```cs
[Test]
public void Create_WhenPassedInvalidOrder_StillPersistsIt()
{
    //Arrange
    var order = new Order(); 
    var mockOrderRepo = new Mock<IOrderRepository>();
    var customerService = new CustomerService(mockOrderRepo.Object);

    //Act
    Assert.Throws<ArgumentException>(() => customerService.Create(order));

    //Assert
    mockOrderRepo.Verify(o => o.Save(order), Times.Once());
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to exclude `[ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentException))]` and instead use `Assert.Throws` ?

Comment: Yeah, sorry I've left the attribute in the sample code, removed now.

Comment: Yea, now I am able to check both valid and invalid orders. Thanks!